# How to disable main JFrame when open new JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Example now I have a main frame contains jtable display all the customer information, and there was a create button to open up a new JFrame that allow user to create new customer. I don't want the user can open more than one create frame. Any swing component or API can do that? or how can disabled the main frame? Something like JDialog.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest that you make your new customer dialog a modal `JDialog` so that you do not allow input from other dialogs/frames in your app while it is visible.  Take a look at the [modality tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) for details.

Comment: Hi it does exactly what I want. Thank you very much

Comment: On the other hand, modal user interfaces are *very* annoying, so consider to redesign the GUI to allow editing several different users at the same time.

Answer (score 21):

I think you should use this code for the main jframe when you trying to open new one :

`this.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: so simple and actually answer OP question, You have help me.

Comment: Perfect, should've been the accepted answer to "how to disable the main frame." Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late answer but have you considered the Singleton design pattern? It will return the same instance of a class whenever you want the class. So if the user wants a frame to enter the details, there will only be one frame open (same instance)

It goes something like this:

```
private static MySingleFrame instance = null; //global var

private MySingleFrame() { } //private constructor 
private static MySingleFrame getInstance()
{

if(instance == null)
{
instance = new MySingleFrame();
}

//returns the same instance everytime MySingleFrame.getInstance() is called
return instance; 


}
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `firstFrame.setVisible(false)` on the first frame. This will make it hidden..

if you want a more general approach you could have a reference to the current displayed frame somewhere and change it when a new frame requests to be shown

```
JFrame currentFrame;

void showRequest(JFrame frame)
{
  currentFrame.setVisible(false);
  currentFrame = frame;
  currentFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: i want the main frame still there just want to make sure the user only open one create frame. I was thinking to disabled to button, but is there any other good practice to implement ?

Comment: you can try with __.setFocusable(false)__, this will keep the frame but the user won't be allowed to click anything inside it..

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. I tried to do it like 

createButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {     
         ...
 createFrame.setVisible(true);
 mainframe.setFocusable(false);
    }
});
But I still can click the create button on main frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 private void btn_NewFormActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

             this.hide();
             new Frm_NewFormUI().setVisible(true);

 }
```