# Set JFrame Completely inactive till another Jframe is Closed

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe

I'm new to Java.

Yet, I've project to do with ; 
1. a Main **JFrame1** & 
2. In JFrame1 I've got a **Button1** for JFrame2.setVisible(true); &
3. another **JFrame2**.

What I need to know is: When User Clicks JFrame1->Button1

1. How to make JFrame1 Completely inactive so that users can't either click a button on JFrame1 or focus JFrame1 while JFrame2 is active.
2. I need to set, when JFrame2 is closed all of above like clicking/ Focusing are possible.

Thank You !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait for a JFrame to close before continuing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335733/how-to-wait-for-a-jframe-to-close-before-continuing)

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable main JFrame when open new JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029079/how-to-disable-main-jframe-when-open-new-jframe)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at using a [modal dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). It will prevent focus being switched to its parent window.

Comment: Yep, 1+ this same question gets asked over and over again and the answer is always the same -- use a modal JDialog or JOptionPane. Else you're stuck with using a WindowListener, but that's a more kludgy solution.