# disable and enable Buttons when ClosingWindow

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener

sorry for my bad english.
I would like to be able to open a new JFrame (prova ()), disable the button "hello", and closing the JFrame (prova ()) rehabilitate the button "hello". But I do not understand how to use WindowListener

```
public class ciao extends JFrame implements ActionListener{


      JButton c = new JButton("hello");
        JButton b = new JButton("ciao");
ciao(){

      JFrame f = new JFrame();  
      f.setTitle("ciao");
      f.setSize(200,200);
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.setVisible(true);

      c.addActionListener(this); 
      b.addActionListener(this); 
      f.add(b);
      f.add(c);
      f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     }






@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{


    if(e.getSource()==c)
    {
    JFrame p = new prova(); 
    c.setEnabled(false);
    p.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
    {
        public void WindowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
           c.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });
    } 

    if (e.getSource()==b)
    {
    System.out.println("booooooooooo");
    }      
}}
```

Comment: Use a modal JDialog not a JFrame as this is precisely what a dialog was built to do. Closing as a duplicate.

Comment: yes ok, but I'm studying WindowListener, there are no solutions?

Comment: I told you the solution: don't use a 2nd JFrame. The 2nd dependent window should be a modal JDialog. If you search on this subject any, you'll see this same answer anywhere you look. Please check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029079/how-to-disable-main-jframe-when-open-new-jframe).